# Splitting string on white characters?

Tags: python

I'm using python and I'm simply trying to split a string on white characters (white spaces, tab, new line, etc.) and put it on an array. If I use:

```
result_array = result.split("\s+")
```

it doesn't works. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to split on whitespace itself just use `split()` with no arguments.  The [`split()` for strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) doesn't take a regular expression, though there is an [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) function that will allow you to split based on a regular expression if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
result_array = result.split()
```

`str.split()` splits on whitespace by default and won't accept regular expressions anyway.

Comment: Oh it'll *accept* regular expressions, but it won't treat them *as* regular expressions :)